# MySQL Foreign Key On Delete

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relationships

I am trying to figure out relationships and deletion options.

I have two tables, `User` and `UserStaff`, with a 1:n relationship from `User` to `UserStaff` (a user can have multiple staff members).

When my `User` is deleted, I want to delete all of the `UserStaff` tables associated with that `User`. When my `UserStaff` is deleted, I don't want anything to happen to `User`. I understand that this is a cascading relationship, but I'm not sure which way.

i.e. Do I select the existing foreign key in my `UserStaff` table and make it cascading, or do I create a new foreign key in `User` and set that to cascading?

Comment: I guess you meant "delete all the UserStaff entries", not "delete all the UserStaff tables"

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, it's possible. You should make the FK in UserStaff table. In this way:

User Table

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

UserStaff Table

```
CREATE TABLE `UserStaff` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `UserId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `UserId` (`UserId`),
  CONSTRAINT `UserStaff_ibfk_1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) 
    REFERENCES `User` (`Id`) 
    ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: So, I just make the foreign key in the `UserStaff` table "cascade" then, got it!

Answer (score 10):

From [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key#CASCADE):

> **CASCADE**
>
> Whenever rows in the master (referenced) table are deleted (resp. updated), the respective rows of the child (referencing) table with a matching foreign key column will get deleted (resp. updated) as well. This is called a cascade delete (resp. update[2]).

Here, `User` is the master table, and `UserStaff` is the child table. So, yes, you'll want to create the foreign key in `UserStaff`, with `ON DELETE CASCADE`

Answer (score 3):

It's been a while since I've used this, but here goes (btw, I use Toad for MySql - a great IDE, and it's free too - http://www.toadworld.com/Freeware/ToadforMySQLFreeware/tabid/561/Default.aspx!)

You need to add a Constraint to the User table. If you have an id column (and the corresponding foreign userid key in UserStaff) then the SouceColumn should be id, the destination table UserStaff and the destination column userid. You can then set the OnDelete action to be 'Cascade'

The other options are pretty self-explanatory - Restrict limits values to the values in the source column, Set Null sets the foreign key matches to Null and No Action does, er, nothing.

This stuff is very easy to do via the Toad IDE. I used MySqlAdmin tools for ages but recently discovered Toad (and it has diff and compare tools too!).

Answer (score 3):

The ON DELETE CASCADE is specified on the foreign key in the `UserStaff` table. For additional info on foreign keys the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html) has a number of examples. The `User` table does not have a foreign key pointing to `UserStaff`, so it will not be affected by changes to the `UserStaff` table.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way might be to make two quick tables and try it out. But since you didn't I can tell you that the outcome will be that it work the way that you want to.

When you have a table `User` and a table `UserStaff` were a field in `UserStaff` uses a foreign key to reference a field in `User`; then if you delete a record from `UserStaff` that will be removed  wihtout having any affect on the `User` table. The other way around will delete all records related to that record.

**Short version:** A field in `UserStaff` should reference a field in `User` with CASCADE