# how to design database for easy update and deletion of rows which form binary type of concept?

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am implementing some retweet type of concept. Now, there can be millions of retweet ( 1-2, 2-3, 3-4, 4-5 ...).

If I delete retweet from 2 then it should also remove from 3, 4, 5, ...  To delete this, I have to make that many query as join won't help me.  How can I do this deletion for such large number of queries quickly?

Comment: Here's the answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333302/mysql-foreign-key-on-delete

Comment: hey thank you for the link. I am new to mysql so dint knew about cascade. Well, this will solve my problem. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look to "[DELETE/UPATE on CASCADE with FOREIGN KEYs for MYSQL](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/MySQL/0080__Table/FOREIGNKEYONDELETECASCADEONUPDATECASCADE.htm)" post. HOpe this helps.