# how to change CONSTRAINT in this table for my project

Tags: mysql, constraints

Hi i make a table from this tutorial [MySQL Foreign Key On Delete](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8333302/mysql-foreign-key-on-delete) and this work good for my project

user table :

```
CREATE TABLE `User` (
`Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

UserStaff Table :

```
CREATE TABLE `UserStaff` (
`Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`UserId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
KEY `UserId` (`UserId`),
CONSTRAINT `UserStaff_ibfk_1` 
FOREIGN KEY (`UserId`) 
REFERENCES `User` (`Id`) 
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

my question is : whate is UserStaff_ibfk_1 ?
can i change it to example_name or not

thanks

Comment: UserStaff_ibfk_1  is the name of the constraint you can simply change it

Comment: thanks fordev you are unique